# How to cut the last field from a shell string

Tags: string, shell, cut

How to cut the last field in this shell string

```
LINE="/string/to/cut.txt"
```

So that the string would look like this

```
LINE="/string/to/"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you could use the "dirname" command. It takes in input a file path, removes the filename part and returns the path. For example:

```
$ dirname "/string/to/cut.txt"
/string/to
```

Answer (score 75):

For what it's worth, a `cut`-based solution:

```
NEW_LINE="`echo "$LINE" | rev | cut -d/ -f2- | rev`/"
```

Comment: I believe this is cutting off the first field, not the last?

Comment: @Michael: I ran it through some tests here, and it seems to work fine. It does actually cut the first field, but it (rather inefficiently) reverses the string before and after, which has the desired overall effect.

Comment: I can confirm this does indeed work, in both Unix and GNU implementations of cut. Obviously the dirname answer is better for the OPs specific use case, but I found this when searching for a general way to drop the last field with cut and this was it.

Comment: @LucasJones It's worth noting that this is many, many times more efficient on multiline input, because `dirname` can only be run on one path at a time. For example, on `find` output the `dirname` alternative is `find ... -exec dirname {} \;`.  The `-exec` makes it extremely slow.

Answer (score 18):

This will work in modern Bourne versions such as Dash, BusyBox ash, etc., as well as descendents such as Bash, Korn shell and Z shell.

```
LINE="/string/to/cut.txt"
LINE=${LINE%/*}
```

or to keep the final slash:

```
LINE=${LINE%/*}/
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it is the fastest and most portable solution as it will work in any POSIX-compliant shell without requiring a `fork`.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "/string/to/cut.txt" | awk -F'/' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i++) printf("%s/", $i)}'
```

Comment: How can we do that using cut?

Comment: @user558134 - not too sure cut support variable for last field, awk is more elegant

Comment: awk solved my issue much more easily and with less code, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

`echo $LINE | grep -o '.*/'` works too.