# How to remove last element of the delimited string using Bash/Sed/Awk/Perl inside bash script

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I have the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
STR1=/home/ubuntu/foo/hicpro_data/output/3333_XX501621_0368_AH2BHTBGX9/CTCF
STR2=/home/ubuntu/foo/hicpro_data/output/3333_XX501621_0368_AH2BHTBGX9/K4me3
```

What I want to do is to remove last element of the `$STR1` and `$STR2` delimited with `/`, and do it inside that bash script.

Yielding in

```
/home/ubuntu/foo/hicpro_data/output/3333_XX501621_0368_AH2BHTBGX9/
```

for both `$STR1` and `$STR2` and assign it to a new variable say `NW_STR1`.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: `echo "${STR1%/*}/"`

Comment: I apologies I mistakenly reopened this. I am not able to make it dup now, could someone please make it dup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563060/how-to-cut-the-last-field-from-a-shell-string  my kid has wrongly touched that option :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Solution 1st:*** If you have GNU `awk` then try following.

```
echo "$STR2" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}NF--'
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Or with parameter expansion of pure BASH(probably BEST solution among all mentioned here).

```
echo "${STR2%/*}"
/home/ubuntu/foo/hicpro_data/output/3333_XX501621_0368_AH2BHTBGX9
```

***Solution 3rd:*** Using `awk` match.

```
echo "$STR2" | awk 'match($0,/\/.*\//){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH-1)}'
```

***Solution 4th:*** using `sub` of `awk` program.

```
echo "$STR2" | awk '{sub(/\/[[:alnum:]]+$/,"")} 1'
```

Answer (score 6):

Just use `dirname`:

```
$ dirname /home/ubuntu/foo/hicpro_data/output/3333_XX501621_0368_AH2BHTBGX9/K4me3
/home/ubuntu/foo/hicpro_data/output/3333_XX501621_0368_AH2BHTBGX9
```